# How many values can a parameter of a specific event hold?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

I've tried to search the Firebase documentation but I can't seem to find how many values a parameter of a specific event can hold.

To my understanding, one event can hold up to 25 parameters; what I need to know is how many values can each parameter hold.

For example, I have an event `create_item` with a parameter `item_name`; the user can type in any name they want. My question is: What is the maximum amount of values (*item_names*) that I will see for that specific parameter.

Maybe I'm going the wrong way about this and there's a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Each parameter name is associated with a single value. This is implicit in using android.os.Bundle to pass the parameters to the logEvent() method. If you try to store a second value for a parameter in the Bundle, it just overwrites any value that was there before.

With String parameters you can work around this to some extent, for instance by using comma-separated lists of values.  If you do, you have to solve problems like what happens if a value in the list contains a comma (or whatever delimiter you choose).